# htmlentities() vs. htmlspecialchars()

Tags: php

What are the differences between `htmlspecialchars()` and `htmlentities()`. When should I use one or the other?

Answer (score 393, accepted):

From the PHP documentation for [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/htmlentities):

> This function is identical to `htmlspecialchars()` in all ways, except with `htmlentities()`, all characters which have HTML character entity equivalents are translated into these entities.

From the PHP documentation for [htmlspecialchars](http://us.php.net/htmlspecialchars):

> Certain characters have special significance in HTML, and should be represented by HTML entities if they are to preserve their meanings. This function returns a string with some of these conversions made; the translations made are those most useful for everyday web programming. If you require all HTML character entities to be translated, use `htmlentities()` instead.

The difference is what gets encoded. The choices are everything (entities) or "special" characters, like ampersand, double and single quotes, less than, and greater than (specialchars).

I prefer to use `htmlspecialchars` whenever possible.

For example:

```php
    echo htmlentities('<Il était une fois un être>.');
    // Output: &lt;Il &eacute;tait une fois un &ecirc;tre&gt;.
    //                ^^^^^^^^                 ^^^^^^^

    echo htmlspecialchars('<Il était une fois un être>.');
    // Output: &lt;Il était une fois un être&gt;.
    //                ^                 ^
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but would you mind to elaborate on what you prefer `htmlspecialchars()` whenever possible, other than the obvious differences?  What situations will using `htmlentities()` cause you problems whereas `htmlspecialchars()` will not?

Comment: Just ran into a problem due to using htmlentities rather than htmlspecialchars! If your site is UTF8 encoded, special symbols like ¡™£¢∞§¶ get turned into little black diamonds with question marks in them because htmlentities doesn't know how to handle them, but htmlspecialchars does.

Comment: @Darius What you're saying doesn't make any sense. `htmlentities` and `htmlspecialchars` can both handle UTF-8 as long as you specify `"UTF-8"` for the third argument.

Comment: @Artefacto To be safe, use `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` too. This should prevent the browser from misinterpreting the encoding and thus showing unwanted characters instead.

Comment: As of PHP 5.4, UTF-8 is the default encoding option (third argument).

Comment: @Darius: We ran into something similar.  Like us, you're probably using PHP older than 5.4.0.  So, inferring from Jonathan's comment, we need to explicitly specify UTF-8 like this: htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

Comment: Addendum from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php): "In PHP 5.6 and later, the [default_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) configuration option is used as the default value."

Comment: This answer does not answer the question, the advised list of "special" characters are processed the same way, proof is here: https://eval.in/936964

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev In your eval.in link, the output from the two function is different - htmlentities encodes the last character, whereas htmlspecialchars does not . htmlspecialchars encodes the characters mentioned on its documentation page. htmlentities encodes those characters _and_ all other characters which are encodable (i.e. they have a HTML entity equivalent). In other words when you say "the advised list of "special" characters are processed the same way,"...yes, of course they are, that's what is supposed to happen. I'm not sure what you're trying to prove? Did you mis-understand?

Comment: @ADyson, thank you for paying attention to my comment. The answer says that the difference is coming from "special" characters. My [example] (https://eval.in/936964) shows that special characters are encoded the same way in both cases. I also managed to find a character that does not encoded the same way, but as you see it is neither `ampersand` no `quotes`. I believe you are right saying - "the advised list of "special" characters are processed the same way,"  but the answer says opposite.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev I see what you mean, in the text right at the end it does appear to have worded it backwards. But the quoted text in yellow from the documentation explains it better.

Comment: @ADyson, thank you. That is why I down-voted this answer and up-voted the other one. I think it should not be an accepted answer.

Comment: @ADyson  that last part where the wording is backwards is from the last edit by Jannie Theunissen. The initial answer was correctly worded. I will edit again to correct.

Comment: "The difference is ... everything (entities) or everything minus "special" characters, like ampersand, double and single quotes, less than, and greater than (specialchars)."

**What?!** :) What am I missing? Such a high-voted & accepted answer, and so wrong! :-o (At least for the most common case, with no args.) And a simple one-liner test could've prevented it! *Both do encode all of the listed chars*, which are, mind you, all [HTML entities](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref), too... The difference is none of those, but chars like accented letters outside of ASCII etc.

Comment: **UPDATE:** Now I see: the last approved edit from Jannie Theunissen screwed it up last year, by adding that "everything minus", and @OctavianNaicu said above he'll reverse it. Octo, did you, and it got rejected, or what's up? Anyway, Tomas, please reverse it to your correct original to stop spreading the wrong information.

Comment: @Sz My edit got rejected by 2 moderators https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21036740

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention. I will fix with a rollback when I am at a computer.

Comment: one thing I noticed that might helpful; htmlspecialchars_decode() doesn't convert &nbsp; (the non-breaking space code) to a space, where as html_entity_decode() does.

Answer (score 399):

`htmlspecialchars` may be used:

1. When there is no need to encode all characters which have their HTML equivalents.

   If you know that the page encoding match the text special symbols, why would you use `htmlentities`? `htmlspecialchars` is much straightforward, and produce less code to send to the client.

   For example:

   ```php
   echo htmlentities('<Il était une fois un être>.');
   // Output: &lt;Il &eacute;tait une fois un &ecirc;tre&gt;.
   //                ^^^^^^^^                 ^^^^^^^

   echo htmlspecialchars('<Il était une fois un être>.');
   // Output: &lt;Il était une fois un être&gt;.
   //                ^                 ^
   ```

   The second one is shorter, and does not cause any problems if ISO-8859-1 charset is set.
2. When the data will be processed not only through a browser (to avoid decoding HTML entities),
3. If the output is XML (see [the answer by Artefacto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3614330/240613)).

Comment: htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") is the best if you are using PHP version earlier than 5.4. ENT_QUOTES is a must to encode single quotes.

Answer (score 111):

This is being encoded with `htmlentities`.

`implode( "\t", array_values( get_html_translation_table( HTML_ENTITIES ) ) )`:

> " &   <   >
>     ¡   ¢   £   ¤   ¥   ¦   §   ¨   ©   ª   «   ¬   ­   ®   ¯   °   ±   ²   ³   ´   µ   ¶   ·   ¸   ¹   º   »   ¼   ½   ¾   ¿   À   Á   Â   Ã   Ä   Å   Æ   Ç   È   É   Ê   Ë
>   Ì Í   Î   Ï   Ð   Ñ   Ò   Ó   Ô   Õ   Ö   ×   Ø   Ù   Ú   Û   Ü   Ý   Þ   ß   à   á   â   ã   ä   å   æ   ç   è   é   ê   ë   ì   í   î   ï   ð   ñ   ò   ó   ô   õ   ö   ÷   ø   ù   ú   û   ü   ý   þ   ÿ   Œ
>   œ Š   š   Ÿ   ƒ   ˆ   ˜   Α   Β   Γ   Δ   Ε   Ζ   Η   Θ   Ι   Κ   Λ   Μ   Ν   Ξ   Ο   Π   Ρ   Σ   Τ   Υ   Φ   Χ   Ψ   Ω   α   β   γ   δ   ε   ζ   η   θ   ι   κ   λ   μ   ν   ξ   ο   π   ρ   ς   σ   τ
>   υ φ   χ   ψ   ω   ϑ   ϒ   ϖ               ‌   ‍   ‎   ‏   –   —   ‘   ’   ‚   “   ”   „   †   ‡   •   …   ‰   ′   ″   ‹   ›   ‾   ⁄   €   ℑ   ℘   ℜ   ™   ℵ   ←   ↑   →   ↓   ↔   ↵   ⇐   ⇑   ⇒   ⇓   ⇔
>   ∀ ∂   ∃   ∅   ∇   ∈   ∉   ∋   ∏   ∑   −   ∗   √   ∝   ∞   ∠   ∧   ∨   ∩   ∪   ∫   ∴   ∼   ≅   ≈   ≠   ≡   ≤   ≥   ⊂   ⊃   ⊄   ⊆   ⊇   ⊕   ⊗   ⊥   ⋅   ⌈   ⌉   ⌊   ⌋   ⟨
>   ⟩ ◊   ♠   ♣   ♥   ♦

This is being encoded with `htmlspecialchars`.

`implode( "\t", array_values( get_html_translation_table( HTML_SPECIALCHARS ) ) )`:

> " &   <   >

Comment: Beware! At first glance, htmlentities looks pretty complete. But it's missing a bunch of really basic and common characters (especially if your clients like MS). Smart quotes (e.g., ’ or &rsquo;), dashes (e.g., — or &mdash), trademark sign (™ or &trade;), and many others will cause it to return null.

Comment: @Jonathan those are in the list. If you're getting an empty result, then you probably specified the encoding incorrectly.

Comment: Or you didn't specify the encoding, and relied on the default, which changed  in PHP 5.4, and then (possibly) again in PHP 5.6, depending on your configuration. Until 2012, the documentation didn't even recommend you specify the parameter. So, if you did not specify the *optional* third parameter, and upgraded PHP, htmlentities used ISO-8859-1 first, then it used UTF-8, then it used whatever's in your php.ini, not throwing an error on any issues, but quietly returning nothing instead. Clearly this could never possibly lead to data loss at some point!

Comment: What is not shown in these lists is (1) that both functions encode spaces (as %20), and (2) that you can set a flag (ENT_QUOTES) so that they also encode single quotes.

Answer (score 100):

Because:

- Sometimes you're writing XML data, and you can't use HTML entities in a XML file.
- Because `htmlentities` substitutes more characters than `htmlspecialchars`. This is unnecessary, makes the PHP script less efficient and the resulting HTML code less readable.

`htmlentities` is only necessary if your pages use encodings such as ASCII or LATIN-1 instead of UTF-8 and you're handling data with an encoding different from the page's.

Answer (score 20):

You should use `htmlspecialchars($strText, ENT_QUOTES)` when you just want your string to be XML and HTML safe:

For example, encode

- & to &amp;
- " to &quot;
- < to &lt;
- > to &gt;
- ' to &#039;

However, if you also have additional characters that are [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) or uncommon symbols in your text then you should use htmlentities() to ensure they show up properly in your HTML page.

Notes:

- ' will only be encoded by htmlspecialchars() to &#039; if the ENT_QUOTES option is passed in. &#039; is safer to use then &apos; since older versions of Internet Explorer do not support the &apos; entity.
- Technically, > does not need to be encoded as per the XML specification, but it is usually encoded too for consistency with the requirement of < being encoded.

Comment: the question is : because my text is supplied by the user , i don't know if i have unicode or uncommon symbols in there. why should i use htmlspecialchars in this case ?

Answer (score 18):

`htmlspecialchars ()` does the minimum amount of encoding to ensure that your string is not parsed as HTML. This leaves your string more human-readable than it would be if you used `htmlentities ()` to encode absolutely everything that has an encoding.

Answer (score 14):

I just found out about the [`get_html_translation_table`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-html-translation-table.php) function. You pass it `HTML_ENTITIES` or `HTML_SPECIALCHARS` and it returns an array with the characters that will be encoded and how they will be encoded.

Comment: This is useful for when you want to make your own function, for example to replace some additional characters or do other magical things.

Answer (score 9):

htmlentities — Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities.

htmlspecialchars — Convert special characters to HTML entities.

The translations performed translation characters on the below:

- '&' (ampersand) becomes '&amp;'
- '"' (double quote) becomes '&quot;' when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
- "'" (single quote) becomes '&#039;' (or ') only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
- '<' (less than) becomes '&lt;'
- '>' (greater than) becomes '&gt;'

You can check the following code for more information about what's htmlentities and htmlspecialchars:

https://gist.github.com/joko-wandiro/f5c935708d9c37d8940b

Answer (score 7):

You probably want to use some Unicode character encoding, for example [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), and htmlspecialchars. Because there isn't *any* need to generate "HTML entities" for "all [the] applicable characters" (that is what htmlentities does according to the documentation) if it's already in your character set.

Answer (score 6):

The  differences between htmlspecialchars() and htmlentities() is very small. Lets see some examples:

> htmlspecialchars

**htmlspecialchars(string $string)**  takes multiple arguments where as the first argument is a string and all other arguments (certain flags, certain encodings etc. ) are optional. **htmlspecialchars**   converts special characters in the string to HTML entities. For example if you have  **< br >**  in your string, **htmlspecialchars** will convert it into **&lt; b &gt;**. Whereas   characters like  µ † etc. have no  special significance in HTML. So they will be not converted to  HTML entities by **htmlspecialchars** function as shown in the below example.

```
echo htmlspecialchars('An example <br>'); // This will print - An example &lt; br &gt;
echo htmlspecialchars('µ †');             // This will print -  µ †
```

> htmlentities

**htmlentities ( string $string)** is very similar to  **htmlspecialchars** and takes multiple arguments where as the first argument is a string and all other arguments are optional (certain flags, certain encodings etc.). Unlike  **htmlspecialchars**,   **htmlentities** converts not only special characters in the string to HTML entities but all applicable characters to HTML entities.

```
echo htmlentities('An example <br>'); // This will print - An example &lt; br &gt;
echo htmlentities('µ †');             // This will print -  &micro; &dagger;
```

Answer (score 3):

One small example, I needed to have 2 client names indexed in a function:

```
[1] => Altisoxxce Soluxxons S.à r.l.
[5] => Joxxson & Joxxson
```

I originally `$term = get_term_by('name', htmlentities($name), 'client');` which resulted in term names that only included the ampersand array item (&) but not the accented item. But when I changed the variable setting to `htmlspecialchars` both were able to run through the function. Hope this helps!