# Escaping double quotes in a value for a sticky form in PHP

Tags: php, validation, forms, filtering

I'm having a little bit of trouble making a sticky form that will remember what is entered in it on form submission if the value has double quotes. The problem is that the HTML is supposed to read something like:

```
<input type="text" name="something" value="Whatever value you entered" />
```

However, if the phrase: "How do I do this?" is typed in with quotes, the resulting HTML is similar to:

```
<input type="text" this?="" do="" i="" how="" value="" name="something"/>
```

How would I have to filter the double quotes? I've tried it with magic quotes on and off, I've used stripslashes and addslashes, but so far I haven't come across the right solution. What's the best way to get around this problem for PHP?

Comment: That's not the resulting HTML, but a representation of the resulting DOM node after your browser has [mis]interpreted and mangled it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want [htmlentities()](http://www.php.net/htmlentities).

`<input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($myValue); ?>">`

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: htmlspecialchars should be enough

Answer (score 11):

The above will encode all sorts of characters that have html entity code.  I prefer to use:

```
htmlspecialchars($myValue, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
```

This will only encode:

```
'&' (ampersand) becomes '&amp;'
'"' (double quote) becomes '&quot;' when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
''' (single quote) becomes '&#039;' only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
'<' (less than) becomes '&lt;'
'>' (greater than) becomes '&gt;'
```

You could also do a strip_tags on the $myValue to remove html and php tags.

Comment: Also, make sure your text encoding is UTF-8 for the above.  You can usually omit that last parameter in htmlspecialchars if you'd like.

Comment: you don't to specify charset http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181299/let-htmlspecialchars-use-utf-8-as-default-charset/6206252#6206252

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use:

```
htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')
```

- `ENT_QUOTES` tells PHP to convert both single and double quotes, which I find desirable.
- `ENT_SUBSTITUTE` and `ENT_DISALLOWED` deal with invalid Unicode. They're quite similar - as far as I understand, the first substitutes invalid code unit sequences, i.e. **invalidly encoded characters or sequences that do not represent characters**, while the second substitutes invalid code points for the given document type, i.e. **characters which are not allowed for the document type specified** (or the default if not explicitly specified). The [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) is undesirably laconic on them.
- `ENT_HTML5` is the document type I use. You can use a different one, but it should match your page doctype.
- `UTF-8` is the encoding of my document. I suggest that, unless you are absolutely sure you're using PHP 5.4.0, you explicitly specify the encoding - especially if you'll be dealing with non-English text. A host I do some work on uses 5.2.something, which defaults to `ISO-8859-1` and produces gibberish.

As **thesmart** suggests, `htmlspecialchars` encodes only reserved HTML characters while `htmlentities` converts everything that has an HTML representation. In most contexts either will do the job. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars) is a discussion on the subject.

One more thing: it is a best practice to keep magic quotes disabled since they give a false sense of security and are deprecated in 5.3.0 and removed from 5.4.0. If they are enabled, each quote in your fields will be prepended by a backslash on postback (and multiple postbacks will add more and more slashes). I see that the OP is able to change the setting, but for future references: if you are on a shared host or otherwise don't have access to `php.ini`, the easiest way is to add

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

to the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: ENT_HTML5 is redundant with htmlspecialchars. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14532168/427545. Nice breakdown though, +1