# let htmlspecialchars use UTF-8 as default charset?

Tags: php, unicode, character-encoding

Is there a way to tell PHP to use UTF-8 as default for functions like `htmlspecialchars` ?

I have already setted this:

```
ini_set('mbstring.internal_encoding','UTF-8');
ini_set('mbstring.func_overload',7);
```

If not, please can you post a list of all functions where I need to specify the `charset`?

(I need this because I am re-factorizing all my framework to get working with UTF-8)

Comment: Suggestion: Write your own string cleaning method. I use one called `strclean()` that basically just calls `htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');` and `trim()`. Less typing, more control over your output, easily switch encoding if needed.

Comment: i am going to do that, the problem is i have to refactor everything in my framework that uses that functions, problem is i don't know which are these fucntions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `htmlspecialchars()` instead of `htmlentities()`. Because it doesn't touch the non-ASCII characters, it doesn't matter whether you use `'utf8'` charset or the default `'latin1'`(*), the results are the same. As a bonus your output is smaller. (Though it does mean you have to ensure you're actually serving your page with the correct encoding.)

(*: there are a few East Asian multibyte charsets which can differ in their use of ASCII code points, so if you're using those you would still need to pass a `$charset` argument to `htmlspecialchars()`. But certainly no such problem for UTF-8.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to tell PHP to use UTF-8 as default for functions like htmlspecialchars ?

Nope, not as far as I know. `mbstring.internal_encoding` will define a default encoding for the mb_* family of functions only.

> If not, please can you post a list of all functions where I need to specify the charset?

I'm not sure whether such a list exists - if in doubt, just walk through the manual and look out for any `charset` parameters.

Comment: walk through the manual? that doesn't seem to be viable pekka xD

Comment: anyway i just saw you are looking for a job in USA, I wish best of luck to you really.