# Resolve PHP post string

Tags: php

I have the following post string:

```
Name=John&Age=33&Question1=What's+your+gender%3F&Answer1=Male&Question2=What's
+your+education%3F&Answer2=Graduate
```

I'm going to have randomly generated amount of questions each time so I won't be able to know number of passed variables. Thus, I am searching for a solution something like:

```
foreach($postItem as $varr) {
    echo $varr["name"].": ".$varr["value"]."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Why is that a "post" string?

Comment: That's a GET URL, not a POST

Comment: Sorry for terminology. It is a serialized ajax post. Isn't called as "post string"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [loop through $\_GET results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222244/loop-through-get-results)

Comment: Ignore what A Duff said - they probably aren't aware that GET and POST payloads look the same.

Comment: @A.Duff post variables are delivered to the server the same way get vars are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post them as `answer[1]`, `answer[2]` etc instead of `answer1`, `answer2`, and PHP will turn them into an array for you.

Comment: Hmm... Should I arrange this in `$.post`? I am using `data: $(form).serialize()` simply. Can you show me a brief example, please?

Comment: You can just make the inputs have the right name, e.g. `<input name='answer[1]' />`, then in your PHP use `print_r($_POST['answer'])` to see how that looks.

Comment: Ah, that simple. Ok then, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
//parse query string to an array ($output)
parse_str($postString, $output);

echo $output['Name'] . ': ' . $output['Age'] . '<br />';

//process questions
$i = 1;
while (array_key_exists('Question' . $i, $output)) {
    echo $output['Question' . $i] . ': ' . $output['Answer' . $i] . '<br />';
    $i++;
}
```

function used http://php.net/parse_str