# complete address $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];

Tags: php, google-chrome

```
    $referer = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
```

I use the above code
For example
Someone who came to my site from Google prints like this :

https://www.google.com/

Can I see the full URL referenced by Google?

For example :

```
google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjuipjfoojuAhUsU....
```

**I mean, I want to print the word searched in Google
And to understand what is the searched and referenced phrase?**

Comment: No.  You won't be able to get that.  The information is not available.

Comment: So how do statisticians extract?

Comment: The url parameters are accessible in your $_GET global. You can loop over them to extract them all, then rebuild the string from the http-referer and params. This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222244/loop-through-get-results

Comment: Thank you. I am a beginner, can you send me an answer?