# Why use htmlspecialchars() when you have htmlentities()?

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [htmlentities vs htmlspecialchars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars)

I know the difference between these two functions. What I want to know is what would be the possible reasons to use `htmlspecialchars()` when you have a more complete option, that is `htmlentities()`?