# How can we secure the URL from: /Contact-Us.php to: /Contact-Us.php/"><script>alert(48)</script>

Tags: php, xss, cross-site

How can we secure the URL from:

`/Contact-Us.php` to:

`/Contact-Us.php/"><script>alert(48)</script>`

This script is added to form input.

```
<input type="text" style="display:none;" name='nameDa' value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?> >
```

AFTER USING THE filter_var($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL); FILTER PROBLEM GOT RESOLVED.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Secure XSS cleaning function (updated regularly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382442/secure-xss-cleaning-function-updated-regularly)

Answer (score 0):

Escape the characters.

Best solution, in my opinion is:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
// &lt;script&gt; alert(44)&lt;/script&gt;
```

[Working example](https://3v4l.org/rchUm)

Comment: How can we identify script tags in the URL. So that we can show some error page.

Comment: Also my .css files are not working on this page. /Contact-Us.php/"><script>alert(48)</script>