# Escape " character in php with echo

Tags: php, html, escaping

Short question:

```
echo '<button type="button" id="add" onClick="addAsset('.$filename.');"> '.$filename.' </button>';
```

this creates a button with an onClick function addAsset(example.png); 
But i'd like to have addAsset("example.png") how do i escape the " character?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO,..try not over using your TAG's,  for this question PHP would have been plenty..

Comment: I usually recommend outputting all the HTML after doing the grunt PHP work. That way you can exit PHP `?>` and write plain old HTML, like this: `<button type="button" id="add" onClick="addAsset('<?= $filename?>')"><?= $filename ?></button>`. I find it much easier to work with, the IDE, editors pick up on it better, etc

Comment: Thanks JimL, that would have saved me a few hours :D

Comment: And you'll divide up your files into what could be considered a controller/model part (the top, grunt work php part) and a view part (the bottom html part). That way you steer into/get used to working with "MVC" patterns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following instead:

```
echo '<button type="button" id="add" onClick="addAsset(\''.$filename.'\');"> '.$filename.' </button>';
```

So, instead of escaping `"` double quote. we are escaping `'` single quote. Which will be more clear when reading the html output.

**Edit:** Better approach would be to write html blocks outside of php blocks like the following:

```
<?php 
//Your PHP COde
?>
<button type="button" id="add" onClick="addAsset('<?= $filename ?>');"><?= $filename ?></button>
<?php 
//More PHP COde
?>
```

As you can see it will be more readable and no escaping would be required. And as you might notice this uses `<?= $filename  ?>`, that is just short for `<?php echo $filename ; ?>`. Learn more about all this in [Escaping from HTML](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)

**Edit 2:** Also, as @deceze have suggested wht if  variable `$filename` might contain quote or some thing you can use the `htmlentities()` for that, it will protect you against XSS if the values of `filename`
 is an input from user. you can use it like below:

```
<button type="button" id="add" onClick="addAsset('<?= htmlentities($filename) ?>');"><?= htmlentities($filename) ?></button>
```

***Also, check [@deceze's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46994093/2394254) below for better understanding of how to protect your code from xss, in this particualr situation.***

Comment: Thank you!! Working flawless :) Can't upvote, not enough reputation, but i will come back :)

Comment: @SvnVldn You are welcome. Please be sure to accept the solution if it was helpful.

Comment: There is a small grey `tick` button under the Voting buttons, you will be able to select it in about 6 minutes. You will have to wait till then.

Comment: What if, by whatever chance, `$filename` contains either a `'` or `"`?

Comment: @deceze I guess the OP would have to google it, &&|| make a new question, if there isn't already one. BTW can you have a look at the downvotes on all the questions on this page? All the answers seem to have one for no reason. Thanks.

Comment: The reason is that all the answers (except https://stackoverflow.com/a/46994093/476) are *wrong and open to XSS.*

Comment: @deceze Ah, so that's why. Well a comment would have been nice :) /shrug

Comment: @deceze I have updated my answer accordingly. Thank you very much for kind suggestion.

Comment: With your update you're still at the risk of *Javascript injection* or at least broken Javascript syntax. (Hint: if `$filename` contains a `'`…)

Answer (score 3):

The end result you'll want to end up with is:

```
<button type="button" id="add" onClick="addAsset(&quot;example.png&quot;);"> example.png </button>
```

Otherwise you'll have broken HTML syntax. The alternative is non-conflicting quotes:

```
<button type="button" id="add" onClick="addAsset('example.png');"> example.png </button>
```

But you'll still have to [escape/encode your input correctly](http://kunststube.net/escapism), in case `$filename` ever contains an undesirable character. The value of the `onClick` attribute must be valid Javascript, *and* valid HTML. So:

```
printf('<button type="button" id="add" onClick="%s"> %s </button>',
       htmlspecialchars(sprintf('addAsset(%s)', json_encode($filename))),
       htmlspecialchars($filename));
```

Comment: When considering xss it is better to use `htmlentities` than `htmlspecialchars` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623236/htmlspecialchars-vs-htmlentities-when-concerned-with-xss

Comment: I don't see why.

Comment: Sorry wrong question attached. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623236/htmlspecialchars-vs-htmlentities-when-concerned-with-xss

Comment: OK, granted, but only in situations you should be avoiding anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20871450/476

Answer (score 2):

Use an escaped single quote `\'`:

```
echo '<button type="button" id="add" onClick="addAsset(\''.$filename.'\');"> '.$filename.' </button>';
```

Comment: That's a short answer for a short question :)

Comment: It will not work right, you will have onClick="addAsset("file")" in html, better do \'

Comment: actually the OP wanted to put " which is not a good practice if you already have double quotes

Comment: Sorry guys, I've changed it to a single quote now :) Thanks for the feedback.