# How to display html class HTML in PHP through echo?

Tags: php

I have a html code:

```
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6" id="filterDiv">
                            <a href="<?php echo $result['company_link']; ?>" class="feature feature-4 feature-center animated" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay=".3">
                                <div class="feature-img">
                                    <img src="images/products/a.jpg" alt="product">
                                </div>
                                <h5 class="title title-sm title-dark"><?php echo $result['company_name']; ?></h5>
                                <span id="myCategory">Category: </span> <?php echo $result['company_category']; ?> ||
                                <span id="myLocation">Location: </span> <?php echo $result['company_location']; ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
```

I want to display this code in PHP. Can anybody Help me out in this? 
Thanks in advance.

I have tried this code but it didn't work:

```
echo "<div class='nk-block nk-block-features-4 mgb-m30'>";
 echo  " <div class='row'>";
 echo "<div class=\"col-lg-4 col-sm-6\" id=\"filterDiv\">";
```

Parse error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\asaworkholding\ajax\category-search.php on line 31
```

Comment: the php code you provided works fine. https://paiza.io/projects/oyM1XTM8vXYzMobaivQgCw

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape " character in php with echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993915/escape-character-in-php-with-echo)

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the posted code comes from the same file and line that's in the error message? I can't see any syntax errors.

Comment: Yup the code is in the same file.

Answer (score -3):

Syntax Error, Please use this code

```
  echo "<div class='nk-block nk-block-features-4 mgb-m30'>";
     echo  " <div class='row'>";
     echo "<div class='col-lg-4 col-sm-6' id='filterDiv'>";
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Your answer does not provide any explanation on solving the question, it's just a single piece of code without any context.

Comment: It was the syntax error which was solved by the upper code segment. Than You!