# How to prevent injection when user is supplying an arbitrary URL parameter?

Tags: php, xss

We have a core PHP application. We got it tested from a security agency and they notified us that our site is having cross site scripting problem. They have reported same issue on most of the pages. The exact error they reported is

Cross-site scripting (reflected)
/users/main/commoncontacts.php [name of an arbitrary supplied URL parameter]

They have also shared the GET request they sent:

/users/main/commoncontacts.php/v8hhi">alert(1)g2gx7

I have spent a lot of time while looking for a solution for this. Everyone talks about different methods for stopping the injection but mainly all talks about parameter value not parameter name. So when a non-existing parameter name is passed then how it shall be happened?

One of my assumption is that I shall use parse_url and parse_str functions to check and suspicious parameter and if find the same then I shall show an error message or send an error response.

Please help.

Comment: Please share the code where you use the parameter name

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` would probably resolve the issue. Don't pass user input direct to the DOM.

Comment: I would recommend `htmlentities` over `htmlspecialchars` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623236/htmlspecialchars-vs-htmlentities-when-concerned-with-xss

Comment: We are not passing user input directly to DOM. Testing agency just provided us the URL they used to show us the issue. My question is about parameter name which we even don't use anywhere in the code.

Answer (score -1):

that's why we need a validation, also trim, htmlentities and htmlspecialchars needed

Comment: Validation on what?

Comment: on your url parametr

Comment: They have provided us following users/main/commoncontacts.php/v8hhi">alert(1)g2gx7. So please let me know how can we validate parameter names? Are you saying that we shall check parameter name on server side?

Comment: if(clean_user_input(isset($_POST['searchtext']))) {
    $_SESSION['searchtext'] = clean_user_input($_POST['searchtext']);
}

where clean_user_input is a funciton which is using trim, stripslashes, htmlspecialchars and mysqli_real_escape_string on the data passed to it.

Comment: You dine true exapt of use clean_user_input  inside if, use it after getting true

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what do you mean?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['searchtext'])) { $_SESSION['searchtext'] = clean_user_input($_POST['searchtext']); } I suggested write so.