# How to convert special html characters in Perl?

Tags: php, perl, htmlspecialchars

In **PHP** it's as simple as [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), how to do it in **Perl**?

Comment: If you are generating HTML using one of the templating modules (e.g.: Template Toolkit, HTML::Mason etc) then the template system will provide a way to escape the output as required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [HTML::Entities](http://p3rl.org/HTML::Entities) module.

```
use HTML::Entities;

my $input = "<em>TEST</em>";
print(encode_entities($input));
```

Comment: Or the `html` filter in Template-Toolkit (hint: Using a template module is a good idea if you are generating HTML).

Comment: Nope,it's different according to this answer, the answer prefers `htmlspecialchars` to `htmlentities`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars/46491#46491

Comment: @Je Rog `HTML::Entities` is equivalent to both of those PHP functions, but its default behavior is like `htmlspecialchars`.