# filter_var vs htmlentities vs htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, escaping, html-entities, htmlspecialchars, filter-var

> **Disclaimer**
>
> > This is not a question about whether we should be escaping for database input.  This is strictly looking at the technical differences between the three functions in the title.

There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars) discussing the difference between [`htmlentities()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) and [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).  But, it doesn't really discuss [`filter_var()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) and the information I found on Google was more along the lines of "Make sure you escape user input before it is echo'd!"

My questions are:

- Why are `htmlspecialchars()` and `htmlentities()` commonly used over `filter_var()`?
- Is there some performance hit from using `filter_var()`?
- Is `filter_var()` not as secure as the other two options?
- Is there any other reason NOT to use the following to encode user input before being `echod`

`filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);`

Comment: `htmlentities`/`htmlspecialchars` allow you to prevent double encoding entities by setting the 4th param to `false`. I don't if it is possible to achieve that via `filter_var`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess (about lack of adoption) would be it's simply because the Filter extension is only enabled by default since v5.2, whereas the html* methods have been around longer.

Comment: I figured it would be something like this for the lack of adoptions.  But, then why did the PHP internal team feel the need to create `filter_var` if there isn't something wrong with the `html*` methods?

Comment: Because filter_var does a lot more than just HTML escaping.

Comment: Ok, then why the need to add this specific functionality to `filter_var()`?

Comment: Because it allows developers to use the same filter method with different arguments to do various kinds of filtering and sanitisation, rather than having to call different methods with different arguments.