# nl2br() won't output line breaks, just 'n'

Tags: php

It's pretty simple, I have a text area post on my website, and if I input:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

into it, it outputs:

```
line 1nline 2nline 3
```

My insert code is:

```
    $status = strip_tags(stripslashes(htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']))));
    $uid = strip_tags(stripslashes(htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uid']))));

    //more stuff

        $sid = rndTxt(16);
        $status = nl2br($status);
        if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $status = addslashes($status);
        }


    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mingle_status (uid,sid,status,`timestamp`) VALUES ('$uid','$sid','$status',now())") or
    print mysql_error();
```

and my output code:

```
while($st = mysql_fetch_assoc($statussql)) {
    $status = stripslashes($st['status']);
    $sid = $st['sid'];
    $td = $st['timestamp'];
?>
<div id="n">
<div id="statuses" class="<?php echo $sid; ?>">
<p><?php echo $status; ?></p>
<div id="statuscomadd" style="background:#E0E0E0;">
<a href="ld.php?uid=<?php $uid; ?>&pid=<?php echo $sid;?>&method=like">Like</a> <a href="ld.php?uid=<?php $uid; ?>&pid=<?php echo $sid;?>&method=dislike">Dislike</a><a href="#" id="time"><?php echo time_since($td) . " ago"; ?></a>
</div>  
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!:)

Comment: that's some combo you have there: `strip_tags(stripslashes(htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string(`, as a general guideline, you call `mysql_real_escape_string` when you insert stuff into db, and `htmlentities` only when you outputs html.

Comment: you'll be wanting to use `mysql_real_escape_string` for escaping your input - addslashes won't cut it

Comment: Maybe use `nl2br()` before you `stripslashes()` and everything else that happens on the first two lines in the above pasted code.

Comment: Is your purpose to actually replace linebreaks with <br /> or maintaining the linebreaks? the "n" thing you're getting looks like it comes from `stripslashes` where \n is turned into simply n.
Edit: I suggest leaving the linebreak alone and using ln2br when you want to output it in html, rather than insert it to you db.

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL Injection here, because you're also calling stripslashes. So that hunk of code does nothing except to mungle up your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need to use `nl2br()` on insert, you will have to use it while displaying in html

and will have to remove `stripslashes` before insert

Answer (score 1):

When inserting just do a `mysql_real_escape_string()` over the values. You only want to change the data (e.g. by using `htmlentities()` when you are going to display it).

Please also consider to stop using `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Another thing: do you realy need `htmlentities()`? Because imo a better solution is to use `htmlspecialchars()`. Otherwise *all* html entities will be replaced.

Also I don't think you need to use `strip_tags()`, because you are already doing `htmlspecialchars()` to protect you against XSS.

Now for you problem is it because you are using `stripslashes()` which breaks the `\n` linebreaks. I think you can just drop those `add/stripslashes`.

Answer (score 0):

You use `strip_tags(stripslashes(htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string())));` which strips the slashes from `\n`.

Just use `mysql_real_escape_string()`, or `htmlentities( ,ENT_QUOTES)` for HTML.

Also, if it's possible use an UTF-8 encoding and `htmlspecialchars()` instead of `htmlentities()`. `htmlentities()` converts every character which has an HTML-representation, while `htmlspecialchars()` converts only the necessary characters. There's no need to convert everything. See: [htmlentities vs htmlspecialchars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars)

Comment: Why `htmlentities()` instead of `htmlspecialchars()`?

Comment: Because the question did not state the used charset, and htmlentities works on more charsets than htmlspecialchars.

Comment: Since when? And what encoding isn't supported by `htmlspecialchars()`?

Comment: ASCII and LATIN-1 for example. The question uses `htmlentities()` too, so I thought it was safer to use that one. Anyway, I'll add something about this in my answer.

Comment: Where is that documented (honest question)? Because AFAIK the supported encodings of both are the same.

Comment: @ONOZ: That's BS. [htmlspecialchars](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/standard/html.c#1475) and [htmlentities](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/standard/html.c#1529) use the exact same implementation. Therefore, they work on the exact same number of charsets. Use the correct API, which in 99.9% of cases (including this one) is `htmlspecialchars`...

Comment: Okay, thanks. I found it here btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars