# PHP How to echo without HTML tags

Tags: php, html, escaping, xss

I have a sort of system where everybody can type whatever he wants. Though, they can also seem to use tags like `<img SRC="..."/>` , `<a href="..."></a>` etc.

How could you exactly prevent this? So as example, if someone types in `<h1>Hello</h1>` the text won't get big, but it would just show `<h1>Hello</h1>`.

If it's not possible to do this please give me an alternative.

Comment: looked at [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make the HTML display as written, you need to "escape" the special characters &, < and > using [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Alternatively, you could remove all the tags and display the remaining text using [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Answer (score 3):

You may try :

```
echo htmlspecialchars('<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>');
```

More info [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: I think, htmlentities is the better way to do so

Comment: In most cases, htmlspecialchars is ok. Have a look to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars). But we both gave right answers.

Answer (score 1):

Just use htmlentities on the string you want to print

Answer (score 0):

the special charcaters or the tags are treayted as different elements. 
before inserting the text in the database you can use **htmlspecialcharacters($string_to_be_inserted)** to escape the html tags.

All the html tags will get removed and only the text will be inserted in the database.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to strip out unwanted HTML tags from your user input

Answer (score -1):

Use htmlspecialchars_decode() function. Its works fine for me...

Use guideline

Your Text with code

```
<?php

    $text = " 
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         Reference site about Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.
    </body>
    </html> ";

    OR

    $text = $row['columnname'];  // Here define your database table column name.

    echo htmlspecialchars_decode($text);  

?>
```

Output:

Reference site about Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.