# smarty not display text with double quotes

Tags: php, smarty

I am using smarty for template.
I am fetching one issue with rendering. i have one variable value of that variable is

```
this is text" data
```

but when i print this value in tpl file it prints only `this is text` except the

```
this  is text" data
```

Why this is happening? please help 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you tried escaping it using `this  is text\" data`

Comment: can you please right the code.

Comment: you should escape when you put it to db. For example via htmlspecialchars() or addslashes(). Then unescape(when you use addslashes) when you print it. Quotes can be changed to &quot; which is valid against html standard, this replacing can be obtained via htmlspecialchars();

Comment: DB: mysqli/pdo prepare() or mysql mysql_real_escape_string() not addslashes or htmlspecialchars, and OUTPUT: htmlspecialchars() as htmlentities() may cause problems with UTF-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In smarty you can escape the data using `{$variable|escape:'format'}`

In this case a format of html should do the trick

`{$variable|escape:html}`

ref: http://smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.escape.tpl

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using quotes in HTML text-nodes anyway (it's invalid).  Use `&quot;` (escaped) instead.

So for your example:

```
this is text&quot; data
```

If your text is coming from your DB, use `htmlspecialchars()` to properly escape it:

```
$val = htmlspecialchars($val);
```

Comment: this value is coming from db.

Comment: escape it on the way out with `htmlentities()`

Comment: I suggest `htmlspecialchars()` not `htmlentities()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars

Comment: +1 my problem is solved but any alternate solution in smarty itself.

Comment: smarty: {$test|escape:html} should do it http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.escape.tpl

Comment: @Waygood Add that as an answer; while `htmlspecialchars` will work, it is much more appropriate to do the escaping in the template engine if one is being used.