# CakePHP: h() vs. Sanitize::html()

Tags: cakephp, sanitization

CakePHP has a global function called [`h`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#h). It's a convenience method for `htmlspecialchars`. CakePHP also has a utility called [`Sanitize`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html), which has a method called [`html`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html#Sanitize%3a%3ahtml). Here is part of its description:

> This method prepares user-submitted data for display inside HTML. This
>   is especially useful if you don’t want users to be able to break your
>   layouts or insert images or scripts inside of your HTML pages.

When should each be used? Is one better than the other?

Comment: Just stick to h() in the view layer as outlined in the doc examples: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#extending-views

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Sanitize::html()` is more versatile: it lets you strip the HTML completely (via `remove` option), and lets you specify the how it handles quoting.

See the source code:
`h()`: http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-function-h.html#160-199
`Sanitize::html()`: http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-Sanitize.html#83-122

EDIT:
`h()`: calls `htmlspecialchars()`
`Sanitize::html()`: calls `htmlentities()`

For discussion on differences, see: [htmlentities() vs. htmlspecialchars()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars)

Comment: Actually, `Sanitize::html()` calls `htmlentities`.

Comment: Must have been asleep. :)  See this question for differences between the 2 PHP functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars . Both prevent XSS so either one is fine for security purposes.