# How to get escaped output in cakephp view file?

Tags: php, cakephp

How to get escaped output in cakephp view file?

This is my current output data:

```
<td><? echo $acc['UserLog']['EventTimestamp'];?></td>
```

I am searching any inbuilt function in cakephp for doing the same

```
<td>
     <?
          echo htmlspecialchars($acc['UserLog']['EventTimestamp'])
     ?>
 </td>
```

Comment: What do you mean escaped, possibly you want to pass this statement to `htmlspecialchars`? Like: `<td><? echo htmlspecialchars($acc['UserLog']['EventTimestamp']) ?></td>`

Comment: Yes, I am looking for inbuilt cakephp function for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159548/cakephp-h-vs-sanitizehtml?