# htmlspecialchars() x htmlentities()

Tags: php, html, htmlspecialchars

I have read their documentation, but I still don't get when to use each of them and their difference.

Let's consider the situation of having a general string in a variable and needing to echo it inside HTML code. If it has any HTML markup in it, I want it converted to HTML code (`<` replaced by `&lt;`, `&` replaced by `&amp;`. If it has UTF special chars that aren't available in HTML code, it's replaced by HTML number (`•` replaced by `&#8226;`).

What's the best function for that?

A harder need: unprintable chars, like `\n`, char(10), char(13), etc, be replaced by their number code, in the case the string is printed inside `<pre>` or any special textarea so that the string be dumped.

Comment: Personally - I'd avoid `htmlentities()` it causes far more problems than it solves, just use utf-8 as your character set throughout (from the database tables, the connector, the application controllers and the views). `htmlspecialchars()` is perfect for just escaping html. If you need something more, try a library like htmlpurifier : http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: google.com difference between such and such: It is easier to search than a make a new post about it. Already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`htmlentities` is a workaround for not having set the character type of the document properly. `htmlspecialchars` is the correct function to use for merely writing text into an HTML document.

As to your second question, I think you're looking for [addcslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php).