# PHP - How To Use %Text% From Textarea To Variable

Tags: php, html, string, variables, textarea

I want to use a special text in textarea as variable that has value.

For example:

A text `%Url%` in textarea is equal to `http://example.com/`.

It is more likely to this:

**If In PHP, it will work like this:**

```
$Url = 'http://example.com';
echo 'This is an example'.$Url.'of a website';
```

output in html: `This is an example http://example.com of a website`

What I want to do is make the textarea work like the code above.

**Textarea**

```
%Url% = http://example.com/

<textarea name='test'>This is an example %Url% of a website</textarea>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejqVn/)

So when the value of that textarea is sent to the server, I want php to read it as:

```
This is an example http://example.com/ of a website
```

or if `$_POST['test']` *(the textarea name is test)* is echoed after submission, then it will output:

```
This is an example http://example.com/ of a website
```

How to achieve it? I saw an app able to do it!

Comment: bog standard "PHP 101" code you could have whipped up yourself: `This is an example <?php echo $_POST['test'] ?> of a website`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this using [str_replace](http://www.php.net/str_replace)

```
echo "<textarea name='test'>" . str_replace("%Url%", "http://example.com", $url) . "</textarea>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If your posting the URL to your PHP then you can just collect it as normal (as Marc B said). But if you're displaying it back to screen then remember to escape it to prevent cross site scripting (XXS) attacks. Use [htmlentities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars)() to escape any incoming HTML.

So something as simple as this should do it:

```
$url = htmlentities($_POST['Url']); 
echo "This is an example {$url} of a website";
```