# Data from database as value of textbox in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

i am setting the value of a few textboxes using the data from the database as shown.

```
$qry="select * from branch where id=4";
$res=$con->query($qry);
$r=$res->fetch_assoc();
```

Actually i am printing the table with the textbox inside the echo statement as below:

```
echo '
<td>Incharge:</td><td><input type="text" name="incharge" size="38" value='.'$r["incharge"])'.'></td>';
```

But the problem is that it is only printing the first string in the textbox.for e.g.if the value of $r["incharge"] fetched is `Ankur Lakhani`, but it is only printing `Ankur`.
Any solution??

Comment: you are missing the quotes : `value='<?=$r["incharge"]?>'`

Comment: ... value="'.$r["incharge"].'" ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output HTML looks like:

```
<input type="text" name="incharge" value=Ankur Lakhani>
```

*as you can tell by the highlighting, it's not interpreted the way* you *expect.*

It is interpreted as:

```
<input type="text" name="incharge" value="Ankur" Lakhani="Lakhani">
```

Add quotes to ensure the whole value is used:

```
<input type="text" name="incharge" value="Ankur Lakhani">
```

You should also add escaping incase your string contains HTML sensitive characters like `"` and `>`

```
<input type="text" name="incharge" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($r["incharge"]); ?>"/>
```

Relevant: [htmlentities() vs. htmlspecialchars()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars)

Answer (score 1):

When you output data as value of a text input you should escape it,
using the htmlentites function :

```
<input type="text" name="incharge" value="<?php echo htmlentities($r["incharge"]); ?>"/>
```

Reference: https://www.php.net/htmlentities

Answer (score 0):

you forgot setting quotes "" for your value.

try this:

```
<?php
$qry="select * from branch where id=4";
$res=$con->query($qry);
$r=$res->fetch_assoc();
?>
<input type="text" name="incharge" value="<?php echo $r['incharge'];?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is in your client side then it will this one

```
'$r["incharge"])'
```

change it to

```
"$r['incharge'])"
```

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
value = "<?php echo $r['incharge']; ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="text" name="incharge" value="<?= $r['incharge'];?>">
```

or use like `<?= htmlspecialchars($r['incharge'])?>`

Must Enable your Short_open_tag on your config file