# Sending MySQL data to page through link in a table

Tags: php, html, mysql

We are currently working on a game shop website and have hit a roadblock regarding the purchase link.
The link displays within a mysql table and each link sends the user to the same page.
This is necessary as we will be adding new games to the database and want to do using only a mysql command to make the site as efficient as possible.

This is the code of the table (ignore the fact that the purchase link displays the 'gameCodes'.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['gameName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['pointsValue'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . '<a href="Purchase.php">'. $row['gameCodes'] .'</a>' .  "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

What I am wanting to do is send the game code of the game that corresponds with the row the link is on to the Purchase.php page to then process the purchase.

Any help is appreciated greatly.

Comment: You can put the game code in a variable in the link, but I would make sure you do quite a bit of SQL injection protection especially when dealing with products and purchasing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my answer deals with not only passing variables from url to your page....but passing it in *clean* way

- First, make sure that url URL  [properly encode using "PHP urlencode"](https://www.php.net/urlencode)

> ```
> echo "<td>" . 
>         '<a href="Purchase.php?gameCodes='.urlencode($row['gameCodes']) .'">'.
>             $row['gameCodes'] . 
>         '</a>' .
>     "</td>";
> ```

- Then to fetch the data [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) from the url variable if any:

  `echo (strip_tags($_GET['item']));`

**why is this needed??**

Since you are fetching the values from URL, assume i manually change the url to :

```
Purchase.php?gameCodes=<script>alert("hello")</script>
```

then without proper handling, `gameCodes` variable value will be fetched and it would `alert` "hello" on the page

Comment: @ChrisPBacon : welcome...i'll suggest if u look into htmlentities too....they are helpful if u are showing user given content on your page!!! http://in3.php.net/htmlentities | and | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 1):

I think you can put the `gameCodes` id directly in the link

```
echo "<td>" . 
        '<a href="Purchase.php?gameCodes='. $row['gameCodes'] .'">'.
            $row['gameCodes'] . 
        '</a>' .
    "</td>";
```

Now you can process the code from the purchase page and retrieve it with `$_GET`

```
$_GET['gameCodes'];
```

Comment: Thanks so much, how would we handle the game code on the Purchase.php from this method?

Comment: @chrispbacon you can handle with `$_GET` as i wrote

Comment: @ChrisPBacon : not asking you to upvote or accept my answer...but do look into it...it'll help u understand about securing your data!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about sending it through the URL like follow:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['gameName'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['pointsValue'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . '<a href="Purchase.php?'.$row['gameCodes'].'">'. $row['gameCodes'] .'</a>' .  "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 }
echo "</table>";
```

and then process to the purchase using the code sent in the URL
let me know if it corresponds to what you need.