# Safe way to escape iframe srcdoc value in PHP?

Tags: php, html, iframe, escaping

Which PHP function is suited to escape HTML for usage in `<iframe srcdoc="???">`?

I found two candidates: `htmlspecialchars()` and `htmlentities()`. Which one should be used to allow *any* possible HTML code to be escaped properly?

Comment: did u read manual?...

Comment: You should be using the `htmlspecialchars()` as `htmlentities()` is a pretty _overkill_ compared to the former.

Comment: Did you try to google .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars

Comment: Of course I did. And I see the difference. But I did not understand if htmlspecialchars() is sufficient for that special application or if htmlentities() is necessary (and why).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`htmlspecialchars()` does everything you need it too. `htmlentities()` is for special use cases, like Chinese characters, where you may want to escape them, even though it is not 100% required. `htmlspecialchars()` seems to be sufficient to protect you from any type of XSS.