# How to echo string with special characters?

Tags: php

I have the below string (in Turkish):

```
$string = "Otpor lideri Maroviç: Gezi eylemcileriyle temasımız olmadı";
```

However, when I attempt to echo the string, I get the below result:

> Otpor lideri Maroviç: Gezi eylemcileriyle temas?m?z olmad?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: use htmlentities function

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all:

```
$string = "Otpor lideri Maroviç: Gezi eylemcileriyle temasımız olmadı";
echo htmlentities($string);
```

And make sure to add... to your head

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: If it worked, please accept my answer, as I gave you working code, first.

Answer (score 2):

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
$string = "Otpor lideri Maroviç: Gezi eylemcileriyle temasımız olmadı";
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your file with code editor ex. Notepad++ and use "Convert to UTF-8" function.
This should help. Here in Poland we are also using special characters and this is a common problem.