# How to avoid css and scripting effect when input on textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Problem i have a textbox `<input type="text" name="message" placeholder="message">` what I want is to avoid css inputs and scripts.
cause when i type EFFECTS the text turns red and has been save to my database, same effect when script is type. Need help pros. Thanks.

Comment: If things are getting inadvertently saved to your database .. That's an injection problem.  You need to sanitize your input message on the server side (php etc) before you process it.  a little reading material .. http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Is there any simple way to implement and avoid css and scripting?

Comment: There are frameworks that have sql injection protection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).
Wikipedia:

> Cross-site scripting (XSS) is a type of computer security vulnerability typically found in web applications. XSS enables attackers to inject client-side script into web pages viewed by other users

To defend against XSS you need to convert `<` and `>` into html entities when you do the output, by using one of the following functions: [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

You can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars) to decide which one to use.

Alternative, if you want to allow only some tags, look at [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.