# I don't want to convert & into &amp; when using htmlspecialchars()

Tags: php

I am allowing users to input anything , I am sending( to database)  `&lt;` for `<` And `&gt;` for `>` by using jquery on client side , And we know still a user can post bad things in database , So i am also using `htmlspecialchars();`

Now this function is converting the `&` into `&amp` , and whole `&lt` converts into `&amp;lt`, So this don't appears as '<' 
for users in browsers. So thats why i don't want `htmlspecialchars()` to convert `&` into `&amp;` ,So that user can see `<` tags after browser parse `&lt;` as `<`

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Btw i want to keep client site conversion.

Comment: This is the wrong approach. You should let the users send anything, and store it in the database as is. Then when you display it, use `htmlspecialchars()` to prevent XSS.

Comment: The problem is that when the server receives the request, it has no way of knowing which `&` come from the user and have to be encoded, or they come from you converting `<` and `>` and should be left alone.

Comment: And btw Why `&` needs to convert into `&amp;` ?@Barmar

Comment: I think you should use `htmlspecialchars_decode()` before storing into the DB, then use `htmlspecialchars()` when displaying what you retrieve.

Comment: The reason `&` needs to be converted to `&amp;` is because `&` has special meaning in HTML -- it's the beginning of all those entity sequences like `&lt;`.

Comment: does Converting `&` really  any help to prevent xss? , AND Can i use `htmlentites()`@Barmer

Comment: You have to do it for consistency. Suppose the user types `&lt;` into the DIV? If you don't convert that `&` to `&amp;`, you'll send `&lt;` just like you would for a converted `<`. Then when you display it, it will be displayed as `<` instead of `&lt;` that he typed.

Comment: `htmlentities` and `htmlspecialchars` are very similar. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars

Comment: Great! I will try to use `htmspecialchars_decode();` , thanks for ur help ,and  Happy new year,  May god bless you ,@Barmar