# Problems with special chars in an <option>

Tags: php, html

i have some data with special characters saved on a table of my database (*e.g.* **ç**)

When i need to print that data i use the php function **htmlentities** and i add this in my page head

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

All works without problem... **BUT** if i print that data into an option of a dynamic menù it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
<select name="group" id="group" style="width:220px">   
  <option value="0">Choose a Group</option>   
  <?php  
  $ls_groups = ...; // calling function of a class
  foreach ($ls_groups as $dett){
    echo "<option value=" . $dett->id . " " . ($dett->id == $myGroup ? "selected" : "") .  ">" . htmlentities($dett->description,ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")  . "</option>";
  }
  ?>  
</select>
```

Where i can search the problem?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

This is what i take **only** if printed in the options
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVmvC.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Please specify exactly what goes wrong and perhaps give an example.

Comment: Also, check if your PHP file is UTF8 encoded. Common mistake if you use special character

Comment: **nvisser** Thanks for reply, added an image!

**PavelJanicek** yeah, just for say it works everywhere instead of in the options!

**Pete** i have 2 servers, config of php.ini & httpd are equals, on one it work, on another nothing! 
Any idea?

Comment: With other languages than English it is always detective work. Can you please show how you call `$ls_groups` variable? There can be problem. Also check [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function

Comment: no problems in $ls_groups if i save the "htmlentities" into a var and print it after (out of the options) it works. Also iconv doesn't work :(

Comment: Then please paste the code what it does when $ls_groups is filled in. The error will most probably be either in that function or in difference between printing it out in the option and "outside" of it

Comment: Also show how it prints out without any error - what **exact** code do you use. Without these informations, it is hard to help you

Comment: $ls_groups hasn't any role... if i change that part in a direct assignment the problem persist. `htmlentities($dett->description,ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")` out of the option it work, if i put in option it fails. Just for explain   `$ls_groups = $class->query() ` and return an array of object

Comment: @Luca do you realize that you are the one in need of help? Please do not make my guesswork even harder than it is and let me help you. There must be error in your code and most probably it is in the parts you are reluctant to show. If you do not want to show your code, then do not expect to be helped

Comment: Also, while at it, check character set of your database

Comment: @PavelJanicek i understand you are here for help but... if character set of db is the problem it always fail... in the $ls_groups there is a query in the class and i can't post it... i had removed all the part of $ls_groups and assigned the value of data in a variable and maked the code so: `echo "<option value=1>" . htmlentities($variableWithData,ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")  . "</option>";` still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try htmlspecialchars() or set charset 'ISO-8859-1'

Reference
[htmlentities() vs. htmlspecialchars()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars)

Comment: All test failed :(