# How to add backslash before every special character in php

Tags: php, regex

I want to add backslash before every character in php

below is my string

```
AT POST :- SARIGAM, (BHANDARI STREET)
PIN : 396155 STATE: GUJARAT 
VALSAD GUJARAT   396155 
India
```

Some special character are not i this string but answer should be valid for all the special character.

I have tried below, but not able to success.

```
if (preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $address))
            {               
                str_replace('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', "\\", $address);
            }
```

Comment: Why not just use `preg_replace()` instead of combining `preg_match()` with `str_replace()`?

Comment: Let's also take a minute to question the purpose here. SQL escaping? Shell commands?

Comment: You might also want [htmlentities() and/or htmlspecialchars()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars/46491#46491)

Comment: *"but answer should be valid for all the special character"* How do you define "all the special characters"? Which are special, which are not?

Comment: @LOKESH attention here

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace all non-alphanumeric and whitespace characters with a backslash and the character:

```
echo preg_replace('/([^A-Za-z0-9\s])/', '\\\\$1', $address);
```

Output:

```
AT POST \:\- SARIGAM\, \(BHANDARI STREET\)
PIN \: 396155 STATE\: GUJARAT 
VALSAD GUJARAT 396155 
India
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/BDU5B)