# php echo stops rendering the page half way while laravel blade template works fine

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have a mcqs website, the problem is that when i try to load a quiz page with multiple questions and their answers, it loads fine.

**Working code:**

```
@foreach ($question->answers as $answer)
                  <span style="display:inline-block">
                      {{$answer->content}}
                   </span>
@endforeach
```

Not Working Code:

```
@foreach ($question->answers as $answer)
              <span style="display:inline-block">
                  {!! $answer->content !!}
               </span>
@endforeach


{!! $answer->content !!} is the same as echo $answer->content
```

**however** for the same code when i try to render the answers with HTML formatting using `<?php echo` , the page stops rendering midway. forexample if say the page was to load 30 questions , it will only load 10 and stops rendering . Even when i tried using `{!!$answer->content!!}` , the problem remains the same.

Note: i am returning set of questions using the below code:

```
 $questions = Question::all()->where('exam_id',$exam_id)->random($questionsCount)->shuffle();
 return view('quiz',compact('exam','questions','questionsCount','t'));
```

I have one to many relationship setup so i can extract the answers of the question using `$question->answers`
it works fine when i don't echo any answer content.

Anyhelp will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Probably would help to show the exact line where you `<php echo ...`, might be an issue with closing the command segment. Also, you said the code above (blade) works fine.  But then you say that using `{{$answer->content}}` fails?  Are you using blade or are you saying that you are using that notation inside php and it fails?

Comment: sorry i updated the question it fails when i use `{!!$answer->content!!}`

Comment: This is the same as echo $answer->content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an issue with unescaped text.  When you use the blade template's escape method (`{{ }}`) it is successful.  When you use the unescaped method, (`{!! !!}`) it fails.  This is the same when using the *unescaped* php `echo`.

There is likely some type of character in one of your questions that is causing a break of the loop or php echo.

To fix, use the blade escape `{{ }}` or php escape ([`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) etc) in the echo.

[htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars) is worth checking out as well.

Comment: thanks a lot,  using `echo htmlspecialchars($answer->content)` solved my problem.

Comment: However this doesn't echo HTML instead it only echoes the html as string!

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem - it was clearly some character that was stopping the loop.  As you noticed, you are now producing *escaped* text instead of the HTML.  This solves the original problem, but now you will have to *print* the characters as you want them on the screen.  You'll either need to clean the input before (as it hits the DB), or un-escape it within display.  If it is something that is breaking your loop - you are likely better off cleaning your data.  But, if you want to show the original tags, research php escape and how to display those strings :)

Comment: in one answer it was `<>` that was breaking the loop. Where can i find list of characters that break code, also what could be done to them to display them as string and not html when required.

Comment: To start - look at whatever creates a tag or an escape (like `<>` or `@` or `;` for example) - just characters that signal a browser that something is coming, or a language, like PHP that it is time to end a line.  Interestingly, you can't type an unescaped `<>` on this site's comments without it being ignored!  For display - research how to translate the strings back - it will depend on how you encode / escape them, but it is a good lesson to learn as you will have to make decisions on how you want to do it from both sides (encode and decode).