# What's the best practice in preventing XSS attack in php for search input?

Tags: php, xss

`htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()` can be used to mask the user input, but which one is better for optimising search results? Will some search result be omitted because some characters are replaced?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)

Comment: Perhaps you want to check out the differences yourself as answers have been given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars

Comment: @angel.bonev Thanks for your suggestions, but I'm aware of what's these two function does. My concern was if I use this function, would it negatively affect my search function, and if it does, can I solve that. (The user input was for search)